# Replace string before brace in Python-script

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I modified jtaubers python script to convert betababel-code to the original greek letters. After some modifications (and help!) I got the script to run.

```
# beta2unicode.py
#
# Version 2004-11-23
#
# James Tauber
# http://jtauber.com/
#
# You are free to redistribute this, but please inform me of any errors
#
# USAGE:
#
# trie = beta2unicodeTrie()
# beta = "LO/GOS\n";
# unicode, remainder = trie.convert(beta)
#
# - to get final sigma, string must end in \n
# - remainder will contain rest of beta if not all can be converted

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = [None, {}]

    def add(self, key, value):
        curr_node = self.root
        for ch in key:
            curr_node = curr_node[1].setdefault(ch, [None, {}])
        curr_node[0] = value

    def find(self, key):
        curr_node = self.root
        for ch in key:
            try:
                curr_node = curr_node[1][ch]
            except KeyError:
                return None
        return curr_node[0]

    def findp(self, key):
        curr_node = self.root
        remainder = key
        for ch in key:
            try:
                curr_node = curr_node[1][ch]
            except KeyError:
                return (curr_node[0], remainder)
            remainder = remainder[1:]
        return (curr_node[0], remainder)

    def convert(self, keystring):
        valuestring = ""
        key = keystring
        while key:
            value, key = self.findp(key)
            if not value:
                return (valuestring, key)
            valuestring += value
        return (valuestring, key)

def beta2unicodeTrie():
    t = Trie()

    t.add("*A",      u"\u0391")
    t.add("*B",      u"\u0392")
    t.add("*G",      u"\u0393")
    t.add("*D",      u"\u0394")
    t.add("*E",      u"\u0395")
    t.add("*Z",      u"\u0396")
    t.add("*H",      u"\u0397")
    t.add("*Q",      u"\u0398")
    t.add("*I",      u"\u0399")
    t.add("*K",      u"\u039A")
    t.add("*L",      u"\u039B")
    t.add("*M",      u"\u039C")
    t.add("*N",      u"\u039D")
    t.add("*C",      u"\u039E")
    t.add("*O",      u"\u039F")
    t.add("*P",      u"\u03A0")
    t.add("*R",      u"\u03A1")
    t.add("*S",      u"\u03A3")
    t.add("*T",      u"\u03A4")
    t.add("*U",      u"\u03A5")
    t.add("*F",      u"\u03A6")
    t.add("*X",      u"\u03A7")
    t.add("*Y",      u"\u03A8")
    t.add("*W",      u"\u03A9")

    t.add("A",      u"\u03B1")
    t.add("B",      u"\u03B2")
    t.add("G",      u"\u03B3")
    t.add("D",      u"\u03B4")
    t.add("E",      u"\u03B5")
    t.add("Z",      u"\u03B6")
    t.add("H",      u"\u03B7")
    t.add("Q",      u"\u03B8")
    t.add("I",      u"\u03B9")
    t.add("K",      u"\u03BA")
    t.add("L",      u"\u03BB")
    t.add("M",      u"\u03BC")
    t.add("N",      u"\u03BD")
    t.add("C",      u"\u03BE")
    t.add("O",      u"\u03BF")
    t.add("P",      u"\u03C0")
    t.add("R",      u"\u03C1")

    t.add("S\n",    u"\u03C2")
    t.add("S,",     u"\u03C2,")
    t.add("S.",     u"\u03C2.")
    t.add("S:",     u"\u03C2:")
    t.add("S}",     u"\u03C2:")
    t.add("S;",     u"\u03C2;")
    t.add("S]",     u"\u03C2]")
    t.add("S@",     u"\u03C2@")
    t.add("S_",     u"\u03C2_")
    t.add("S",      u"\u03C3")

    t.add("T",      u"\u03C4")
    t.add("U",      u"\u03C5")
    t.add("F",      u"\u03C6")
    t.add("X",      u"\u03C7")
    t.add("Y",      u"\u03C8")
    t.add("W",      u"\u03C9")

    t.add("I+",     U"\u03CA")
    t.add("U+",     U"\u03CB")

    t.add("A)",     u"\u1F00")
    t.add("A(",     u"\u1F01")
    t.add("A)\\",   u"\u1F02")
    t.add("A(\\",   u"\u1F03")
    t.add("A)!",    u"\u1F02")
    t.add("A(!",    u"\u1F03")
    t.add("A)/",    u"\u1F04")
    t.add("A(/",    u"\u1F05")
    t.add("E)",     u"\u1F10")
    t.add("E(",     u"\u1F11")
    t.add("E)\\",   u"\u1F12")
    t.add("E(\\",   u"\u1F13")
    t.add("E)!",    u"\u1F12")
    t.add("E(!",    u"\u1F13")
    t.add("E)/",    u"\u1F14")
    t.add("E(/",    u"\u1F15")
    t.add("H)",     u"\u1F20")
    t.add("H(",     u"\u1F21")
    t.add("H)\\",   u"\u1F22")
    t.add("H(\\",   u"\u1F23")
    t.add("H)!",    u"\u1F22")
    t.add("H(!",    u"\u1F23")
    t.add("H)/",    u"\u1F24")
    t.add("H(/",    u"\u1F25")
    t.add("I)",     u"\u1F30")
    t.add("I(",     u"\u1F31")
    t.add("I)\\",   u"\u1F32")
    t.add("I(\\",   u"\u1F33")
    t.add("I)!",    u"\u1F32")
    t.add("I(!",    u"\u1F33")
    t.add("I)/",    u"\u1F34")
    t.add("I(/",    u"\u1F35")
    t.add("O)",     u"\u1F40")
    t.add("O(",     u"\u1F41")
    t.add("O)\\",   u"\u1F42")
    t.add("O(\\",   u"\u1F43")
    t.add("O)!",    u"\u1F42")
    t.add("O(!",    u"\u1F43")
    t.add("O)/",    u"\u1F44")
    t.add("O(/",    u"\u1F45")
    t.add("U)",     u"\u1F50")
    t.add("U(",     u"\u1F51")
    t.add("U)\\",   u"\u1F52")
    t.add("U(\\",   u"\u1F53")
    t.add("U)!",    u"\u1F52")
    t.add("U(!",    u"\u1F53")
    t.add("U)/",    u"\u1F54")
    t.add("U(/",    u"\u1F55")
    t.add("W)",     u"\u1F60")
    t.add("W(",     u"\u1F61")
    t.add("W)\\",   u"\u1F62")
    t.add("W(\\",   u"\u1F63")
    t.add("W)!",    u"\u1F62")
    t.add("W(!",    u"\u1F63")
    t.add("W)/",    u"\u1F64")
    t.add("W(/",    u"\u1F65")

    t.add("A)=",    u"\u1F06")
    t.add("A(=",    u"\u1F07")
    t.add("H)=",    u"\u1F26")
    t.add("H(=",    u"\u1F27")
    t.add("I)=",    u"\u1F36")
    t.add("I(=",    u"\u1F37")
    t.add("U)=",    u"\u1F56")
    t.add("U(=",    u"\u1F57")
    t.add("W)=",    u"\u1F66")
    t.add("W(=",    u"\u1F67")

    t.add("*A)",     u"\u1F08")
    t.add("*)A",     u"\u1F08")
    t.add("*A(",     u"\u1F09")
    t.add("*(A",     u"\u1F09")
    #
    t.add("*(\A",    u"\u1F0B")
    t.add("*A)/",    u"\u1F0C")
    t.add("*)/A",    u"\u1F0C")
    t.add("*A(/",    u"\u1F0F")
    t.add("*(/A",    u"\u1F0F")
    t.add("*E)",     u"\u1F18")
    t.add("*)E",     u"\u1F18")
    t.add("*E(",     u"\u1F19")
    t.add("*(E",     u"\u1F19")
    #
    t.add("*(\E",    u"\u1F1B")
    t.add("*E)/",    u"\u1F1C")
    t.add("*)/E",    u"\u1F1C")
    t.add("*E(/",    u"\u1F1D")
    t.add("*(/E",    u"\u1F1D")

    t.add("*H)",     u"\u1F28")
    t.add("*)H",     u"\u1F28")
    t.add("*H(",     u"\u1F29")
    t.add("*(H",     u"\u1F29")
    t.add("*H)\\",   u"\u1F2A")
    t.add(")\\*H",   u"\u1F2A")
    t.add("*)\\H",   u"\u1F2A")
    t.add("*H)!",    u"\u1F2A")
    t.add(")!*H",    u"\u1F2A")
    t.add("*)!H",    u"\u1F2A")
    #
    t.add("*H)/",    u"\u1F2C")
    t.add("*)/H",    u"\u1F2C")
    #
    t.add("*)=H",    u"\u1F2E")
    t.add("(/*H",    u"\u1F2F")
    t.add("*(/H",    u"\u1F2F")
    t.add("*I)",     u"\u1F38")
    t.add("*)I",     u"\u1F38")
    t.add("*I(",     u"\u1F39")
    t.add("*(I",     u"\u1F39")
    #
    #
    t.add("*I)/",    u"\u1F3C")
    t.add("*)/I",    u"\u1F3C")
    #
    #
    t.add("*I(/",    u"\u1F3F")
    t.add("*(/I",    u"\u1F3F")
    #
    t.add("*O)",     u"\u1F48")
    t.add("*)O",     u"\u1F48")
    t.add("*O(",     u"\u1F49")
    t.add("*(O",     u"\u1F49")
    #
    #
    t.add("*(\O",    u"\u1F4B")
    t.add("*O)/",    u"\u1F4C")
    t.add("*)/O",    u"\u1F4C")
    t.add("*O(/",    u"\u1F4F")
    t.add("*(/O",    u"\u1F4F")
    #
    t.add("*U(",     u"\u1F59")
    t.add("*(U",     u"\u1F59")
    #
    t.add("*(/U",    u"\u1F5D")
    #
    t.add("*(=U",    u"\u1F5F")

    t.add("*W)",     u"\u1F68")
    t.add("*W(",     u"\u1F69")
    t.add("*(W",     u"\u1F69")
    #
    #
    t.add("*W)/",    u"\u1F6C")
    t.add("*)/W",    u"\u1F6C")
    t.add("*W(/",    u"\u1F6F")
    t.add("*(/W",    u"\u1F6F")

    t.add("*A)=",    u"\u1F0E")
    t.add("*)=A",    u"\u1F0E")
    t.add("*A(=",    u"\u1F0F")
    t.add("*W)=",    u"\u1F6E")
    t.add("*)=W",    u"\u1F6E")
    t.add("*W(=",    u"\u1F6F")
    t.add("*(=W",    u"\u1F6F")

    t.add("A\\",    u"\u1F70")
    t.add("A!",     u"\u1F70")
    t.add("A/",     u"\u1F71")
    t.add("E\\",    u"\u1F72")
    t.add("E!",     u"\u1F72")
    t.add("E/",     u"\u1F73")
    t.add("H\\",    u"\u1F74")
    t.add("H!",     u"\u1F74")
    t.add("H/",     u"\u1F75")
    t.add("I\\",    u"\u1F76")
    t.add("I!",     u"\u1F76")
    t.add("I/",     u"\u1F77")
    t.add("O\\",    u"\u1F78")
    t.add("O!",     u"\u1F78")
    t.add("O/",     u"\u1F79")
    t.add("U\\",    u"\u1F7A")
    t.add("U!",     u"\u1F7A")
    t.add("U/",     u"\u1F7B")
    t.add("W\\",    u"\u1F7C")
    t.add("W!",     u"\u1F7C")
    t.add("W/",     u"\u1F7D")

    t.add("A)/|",   u"\u1F84")
    t.add("A(/|",   u"\u1F85")
    t.add("H)|",    u"\u1F90")
    t.add("H(|",    u"\u1F91")
    t.add("H)/|",   u"\u1F94")
    t.add("H)=|",   u"\u1F96")
    t.add("H(=|",   u"\u1F97")
    t.add("W)|",    u"\u1FA0")
    t.add("W(=|",   u"\u1FA7")

    t.add("A=",     u"\u1FB6")
    t.add("H=",     u"\u1FC6")
    t.add("I=",     u"\u1FD6")
    t.add("U=",     u"\u1FE6")
    t.add("W=",     u"\u1FF6")

    t.add("I\\+",   u"\u1FD2")
    t.add("I!+",    u"\u1FD2")
    t.add("I/+",    u"\u1FD3")
    t.add("I+/",    u"\u1FD3")
    t.add("U\\+",   u"\u1FE2")
    t.add("U!+",    u"\u1FE2")
    t.add("U/+",    u"\u1FE3")

    t.add("A|",     u"\u1FB3")
    t.add("A/|",    u"\u1FB4")
    t.add("H|",     u"\u1FC3")
    t.add("H/|",    u"\u1FC4")
    t.add("W|",     u"\u1FF3")
    t.add("W|/",    u"\u1FF4")
    t.add("W/|",    u"\u1FF4")

    t.add("A=|",    u"\u1FB7")
    t.add("H=|",    u"\u1FC7")
    t.add("W=|",    u"\u1FF7")

    t.add("R(",     u"\u1FE4")
    t.add("*R(",    u"\u1FEC")
    t.add("*(R",    u"\u1FEC")

#    t.add("~",      u"~")
#    t.add("-",      u"-")

#    t.add("(null)", u"(null)")
#    t.add("&", "&")

    t.add("0", u"0")
    t.add("1", u"1")
    t.add("2", u"2")
    t.add("3", u"3")
    t.add("4", u"4")
    t.add("5", u"5")
    t.add("6", u"6")
    t.add("7", u"7")
    t.add("8", u"8")
    t.add("9", u"9")

    t.add("@", u"@")
    t.add("$", u"$")

    t.add(" ", u" ")

    t.add(".", u".")
    t.add(",", u",")
    t.add("'", u"'")
    t.add(":", u":")
    t.add(";", u";")
    t.add("_", u"_")

    t.add("[", u"[")
    t.add("]", u"]")

    t.add("\n", u"")


    return t

import sys

t = beta2unicodeTrie()

import re
BCODE = re.compile(r'\\bcode{[^}]*}')

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    matches = BCODE.search(line)
    for match in BCODE.findall(line):
        bcode = match[7:-1]
        a, b = t.convert(bcode.upper())
        if b:
            raise IOError("failed conversion '%s' in '%s'" % (b, line))
        converted = a.encode("utf-8")
        line = line.replace(match, converted)

    print(line.rstrip())
```

There is one thing left though. The final sigma "ς" gets not converted like this when it stands at the end of the \bcode{}-Makro. For example here:

```
\bcode{ei)=dos}
```

The script converts it to the normal sigma "σ" Unicode: U+03C3

How do I make the script recognize to convert the "s" when it stands right before the end-brace to the Unicode U+03C2?
This:

```
t.add("S}",     u"\u03C2}")
```

does not do the trick